# Creating Array with properties for each item in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, properties, nsmutablearray

tell me please, how do I create an array in which each element will have a number of properties. For example:

```
array:
  |
  |-item 1 ( property_1-"Name1", property_2-"LastName1", property_3-"Age1");
  |-item 2 ( property_1-"Name2", property_2-"LastName2", property_3-"Age2");
  |-item 3 ( property_1-"Name3", property_2-"LastName1", property_3-"Age2");
  |-…
```

In this case, the different elements of an array can have one and the same property, such as in the code posted above - "**item 3**" has the "**property 2**" is the same as in "**item 1**", and "**property 3**" is the same as in "**item 2**"

Tell me, please, how best to do it and, if not difficult, write a simple example or a link to some tutorial.

Thank you in advance)

Comment: Are the properties same? Or have some patterns? `property_1` has the pattern that has same prefix 'Name' and the number increase one bye one. But `LastName...` and `Age...` does **not** have. So what do you want?

Comment: @sunkehappy - Each element always has all these properties, if you are about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects:

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name1", @"property_1", @"LastName1", @"property_2", @"Age1", @"property_3", nil);
NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name2", @"property_1", @"LastName2", @"property_2", @"Age2", @"property_3", nil);
NSDictionary *dict3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name3", @"property_1", @"LastName3", @"property_2", @"Age3", @"property_3", nil);

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict1, dict2, dict3, nil];
```

If you want to update this later then you should use `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSMutableArray`, respectively.

If you are **not** using ARC, the you need to `release` objects when you are finished with them.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods that I would suggest:

**1. Use a class to store all the properties**

Here's an example:

```
@interface Wrapper : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* property_1;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* property_2;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* property_3;

@end
```

Then you can use it as a dictionary:

```
NSString* value=[myWrapperInstance valueForKey: @"property_1"];
```

But here comes the alternative solution:

**1. Use a NSDictionary to store all the properties**

```
NSDictionary* dict= @{ @"property_1" : @"Name1" ,@"property_2" : @"Name2",  @"property_3" : @"Name3" };
```

Then the solution comes easy:

```
NSMutableArray* objects=[NSMutableArray new];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    NSDictionary* dict= @{ @"property_1" : @"Name1" ,@"property_2" : @"Name2",  @"property_3" : @"Name3" };
    [objects addObject: dict];
}
```

Comment: +1 for solution #1 - almost always better to use object-oriented solution.  To editorialize a bit - I see dozens of questions per week here on SO where the asker is going through convoluted hoops to use `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` to manage his entire model layer only to wonder later why it seems so difficult to manage.